# Wordpress visual editor, how to make changes to image border

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Sorry about my broken english.

I am trying to make some changes in the wordpress visual editor. Basically, I already have a border around an image and I want the border to change width and padding when the mouse hovers it. Here is my current code: img class="wp-image-162 size-medium aligncenter" style="border: 1px solid #696262; padding: 5px; margin: 0px;"

What code should i add so that the border changes when the mouse touches the image? I am a starter on this and the current changes don't work.

I am a beginner and I would need the exact inline code to save me.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin to your wordpress website:
      https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/image-hover-effects-visual-composer-extension/

I think it might solve your problem

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I had already tried this plugin, but it doesn't seem to work that well. The site loads much lower and the images are disfigured. What do you think?